# Custom Silverlight TreeView Template

Tags: templates, silverlight-4.0, treeview

I build tree with Hierarchical datatemplate (with button beside each node) loaded from xml file.

What I want to do is when i press the button beside the node it will open node details in  a popup inside the tree (Like tree sub node)

Any ideas ????

I'm using Silverlight 4

Answer (score 0):

Determine if you want type of layout control you want to use (Canvas, Grid, Stackpanel).
Each has their strengths and weaknesses.

Once you decide on this, start designing the logic... then you start coding.
If you're too lazy and want a control/solution that's alreayd built for you, you can try googling it... which i'm pretty sure you'll find samples/demos/source-code for.

Personally i do recommend you spend time looking for samples and source-code, because a hierarchical treeview is a bit more complex than you might think. In particular, the logic for your node placements so that they never collide with each other could be complex (depending on your level of experience).

If you DO decide to write your own, I applaud you, and you will surely learn way more this way.
Oh by the way, not sure what you mean by hierarchical datatemplate. I suggest you write a usercontrol for a single Node. then maybe write another control (treeview control) that manages all the nodes to present the hierarchy tree.